# Why did Jessie get mad at Walter for destroying the RV

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In *Breaking Bad* S3EP6, Walter knows Hank is looking for the RV so he reaches for the car first.

Badger and his cousin were there when Walt explained his reason for wanting the car to be destroyed. Immediately after that, Badgers call Jessie to tell him about the RV

So, what exactly is Jessie's problem here? Why did he get mad at Walt when he entered the RV? He knows the DEA has a clue about the car and Walt is helping him right now so... What's his deal?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the episode itself, Jessie was left out of the plan and had no idea what was happening. It's not like Badger explained anything properly. Jessie said that RV is as much his as Walt's. That's why he was angry for not being part of the decision-making about RV. Jessie has always been the emotional one, not the calculative clever one to evaluate the situation before acting.

Comment: Also, Jesse and Walt split their business just in previous episode, because Walt got deal with Gus and a new lab and Jesse didn't. So, Walt doesn't need RV lab anymore, but Jesse does to continue his "solo business" after split.

Comment: @user28434 nice point, it does adds up